# Gtk UI with XML: how to put enum values in fields

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I want to be able to put enum values like GTK_ICON_SIZE_DIALOG in the XML file. It is cumbersome to remember numbers to assign to properties. What I am saying is that I want this:

```xml
<property name="icon-size">GTK_ICON_SIZE_DIALOG</property>
```

and not this:

```xml
<property name="icon-size">6</property>
```

without getting an error that GTK_ICON_SIZE_DIALOG isn't an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cannot use `GTK_ICON_SIZE_DIALOG` (or the "nickname" `dialog` defined by the enumeration type) like you could do for any other enumeration in the UI definition file is that the expected value is **not** an enumeration, but an integer. For historical reasons, it is possible to register "custom" icon sizes; the icon sizes provided by GTK out of the box are defined in the `GtkIconSize` enumeration, but additional icon sizes would extend that enumeration on a per-application basis.

Since the expected type is a generic integer, the XML parser cannot turn a string with the enumeration name into an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't; the definition of the XML format just doesn't include that. (They aren't primarily meant to be hand-written, but created with a program like Glade.)

If you wanted to write your XML files like that, you could create an XML pre-processor which would replace the enum names with the values, using GObject-Introspection to determine the values.